# Scalable UI framework for Java EE web application

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks, vaadin

Can anyone suggest a good UI framework that can be used in a Java EE web application?

I will be doing a project that requires to generate a web UI on the fly. Regular JSP page coding makes it hard to do. There is a framework called [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/). It looks good to do a dynamic UI implementation. However, I don't know if it stable for production use. If there is any other good suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/). It's been in production use for years, it's very stable, it's very programmer-friendly, and it can easily handle dynamic UIs.

(But I have to agree that the Vaadin demos look hot)

Comment: +1 for suggesting Wicket and not JSF 1/2. But I'd opt for GWT

Comment: @Pangea I'd only suggest JSF to people I hate, and the OP has done nothing do offend me :-)

Comment: +1 me too for Wicket. If you can try with Scala, I am planning to try Wicket with Scala. Heard that it makes code very concise with all anon classes you need to deal with in Wicket.

Comment: @Nishant yes I've heard of many people who use with wicket with Scala. Seems like a good combo

Answer (score 2):

I would say vaadin would be easier over wicket as the default UI elements look really good.
Wicket, you will need to create your own css to make things look good (other than default html UI)

vaadin 6.5.0 was released a couple of days ago and has been there for a long time but recently made open source probably around 2-3 years ago at most if i remember right.

I love both Vaadin and Wicket and my opinion is that they are the best 2 frameworks out there.
However, for this case, I would choose vaadin cause it is easier to get better looking UI elements

Comment: Yeah, I too think Vaadin is stable enough for any production use. Also, if you're conserned about scalability have a look at CEO Joonas Lehtinen's slides about Vaadin Scalability at http://www.slideshare.net/codento/vaadin-scalabilityslides

Comment: The technology behind Vaadin is over 8 years old, and has been in production in large corporations since 2002. Vaadin was previously known as IT Mill Toolkit, and as Millstone before that. It's not as known as some alternatives (yet) because we rebranded the technology as Vaadin in 2009, and started our marketing efforts from scratch at that time. I don't know Wicket, but AFAIK our primary advantages are 100% Java based API (no Javascript or HTML templates etc) and fully Ajax'ed UI out of the box.